# Installable trigger is just keep getting disabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to install an installable trigger for a googlesheet workspace addon when a button is clicked. The trigger is meant to get fired whenever a cell is modified.

Unfortunately when a cell is modified, the trigger keeps getting disabled. The "disabled reason" (in `Apps Script > Triggers > Last run column in the list`) says: `This trigger has been disabled for an unknown reason.` I have tried calling from `onHomepage()` also.

Here is the code:

```
function createWidgetDemoCard() {
  return CardService
     .newCardBuilder()
     .setHeader(...)
     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .setHeader('Simple widgets')  // optional
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Some text'))
              .addWidget(CardService.newImage().setImageUrl('.../trees-autumn-colors-lake-picutre-600w-1827312116.jpg'))
              .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
                                                  .setText('Create trigger')
                                                  .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
                                                  .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger'))
                                                  .setDisabled(false))))
     .build();
} 

function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('TestMe')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()    //onChange() not working`enter code here`
      .create();
}

function TestMe(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

The authscopes are:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
```

The code from the `TestMe()` function works perfectly in a container-bound script. But because I am developing a Workspace addon, I want in a standalone script.

I can't really find a comprehensive documentation about developing an workspace addon.
Thanks!

Comment: Your issue might be related to this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455263/why-does-time-based-gas-trigger-get-disabled-for-unknown-reason-in-v8. I am not sure though

Comment: It does seem like the same issue