# Google Apps-Script recursive triggers stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have triggers like below :

```
function repeat3() {    
                   var next = ScriptApp.newTrigger("repeat4").timeBased();
                   next.after(3 * 60 * 1000).create();
                   Logger.log("Running repeat 3");
                   copyrows_repeat(25);
      }

function repeat4() {
                     var next = ScriptApp.newTrigger("repeat5").timeBased();
                     next.after(3 * 60 * 1000).create();
                     Logger.log("Running repeat 4");
                     copyrows_repeat(31);
                  }
```

The problem is when i am setting repeat3 to run between 12:1 AM , it just runs repeat3 and close it. The repeat4 function gets a trigger to run 3 minutes after repeat3 but it never runs. Instead in triggers window it shows disabled with reason "The trigger has been disabled with unknown reasons" . Also i dont get any failure email or anything. Can someone suggest what can be done ?

the handler function :

```
function copyrows_repeat(k) {

    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sourcesheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Portfolio_Nifty500');
    let sourceRange = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
    let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    let endRow = sourcesheet.getLastRow() - 1 ;
    sourcesheet.getRange('B3').activate();
    var i; 
    for (i = k;i <= k+5;i++) {                    
    sourcesheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(sourceValues[i][0]);
    Logger.log(sourceValues[i][0]);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }
    }
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60525456/16125139) may be relevant to you problem.

Comment: Where are the handler functions?

Comment: @idfurw : The problem with moving to previous runtime is my code doesnt work as it is. It shows some syntax issue. Also point to note is this was working 7-8 days back.

Comment: @Cooper : Here it is : 
function copyrows_repeat(k) {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourcesheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Portfolio_Nifty500');
  let sourceRange = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  let endRow = sourcesheet.getLastRow() - 1 ;
  sourcesheet.getRange('B3').activate();
  var i; 
  for (i = k;i <= k+5;i++) {
  sourcesheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(sourceValues[i][0]);
  Logger.log(sourceValues[i][0]);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
}

Comment: @Cooper : Added it in question itself as formatting is poor in comments

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Comment: If you are going to trigger those functions from a trigger then you cant pass it parameters without using an intermediate function.